# Facebook login button for my site. What use is this? What is it supposed to do?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

So apparently one of the requirements for my site is to incorporate a facebook login button to log into the site.

I'm not exactly sure what this is supposed to do.  I've been reading the documentation for it and it seems like either I need to be storing some info for this site on facebook somehow, or I need to have the same email/ password for both sites.

Or am I supposed to store some kind of ID or token that coincides with some facebook thing?

I'm just really not sure how to use this or why its useful?

Can someone maybe give me an explanation as the documentation in the developers section doesn't really answer the question, Why should I use this.  Or at least not for a simpleton like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: You can use the facebook account as an account on your site!

The upside here is that people don't have to go through the whole registration process of your page and you can simply use all the data facebook provides from the user. You have also a little bit of a higher chance that it's not a fake account as facebook handles that problem quite well already. Also people just logon to facebook (or most of them are already) and are automatically logged in onto your page as well!

There surely are more up and *also* downsides, but this is not a discussion board!

For the technical part: You create an app on facebook that is practically the link to your page and via that link you can exchange all account details from fb to your page and also you can use (depending on the given permissions) their account to publish something to the news feed/send messages/etc.

Just read a bit more about the [Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) on Facebook which will simply give you all the needed tokens and IDs for the exchange!

Comment: so do I have to use the registration stuff to include the login stuff?  Because I've already set my entire registration process up and all I really need is them to be able to login with their facebook.

Comment: registration stuff ? login stuff ? sorry I don't understand a word

Comment: ok I understand the approach of using the persons facebook account to register a new account on my site, but what about accounts that already exist.  I just want them to be able to login with their facebook accounts.

Comment: actually now that I'm reading more into the Javascript SDK, its becoming a little more clear.  I think I  just let myself get overwhelmed.

Comment: Glad to hear! Anyway regarding your question: When you know got the access token from the user, you have to register/link that in your user database as well, whether it already exist or not.

Comment: Ya thats what I ended up doing.  Im just using the client side full script version from the sdk, then comparing the user token once requested verses whatevers stored in the DB.  And i'll have users in admin panel run some script once with too store the token in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Creating different account for every other site is the most frustrating thing for a user. But if you have a single account that will work on most of the sites then that will solve the problem of remembering passwords and filling the forms for account creation. So with the help of facebook login users don't have to create a new account. All they need to do is use one account everywhere.
This is a great tutorial for FB login http://php-drops.blogspot.com/2011/04/facebook-login-fconnect-graph-api-php.html

Comment: Well yes, this makes sense if youre registering them via facebook from the get go.  But what if your trying to implement this to an existing site with existing users?